# Textbox doesn't exists in current context (Gridview and TemplateField)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, gridview

I am trying to record the input text by storing the value into the string and display it using label text.

However, I get this error because I suspect that that the textbox is inside the templatefield. It works if I put the textbox outside the templatefield.

Here is an error:

[image]

Here is the code for MasterPage.Master.aspx:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="gridviewtemplate.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="gridviewtemplate._default" %> <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server"> </asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:Label ID="lbl_result" runat="server"></asp:Label>

    <asp:GridView ID="grv_test" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds_store" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_test1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_test2" runat="server" Text="Submit Changes" OnClick="btn_test2_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product ID">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_test3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("product_id")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_store" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:websiteConnection %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [product_id] FROM [tbl_cart]">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</asp:Content>
```

Here is the code for default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace gridviewtemplate
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void btn_test2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string test = txt_test1.Text;

            lbl_result.Text = "You have changed the textbox to " + test;
        }


    }
}
```

I have tried other solutions as well by adding the

> protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txt_test1;

inside the **default.aspx.designer.cs**

However, it prompts me an error:

[image]

Is there any other methods to overcome the error?

Comment: your txt_test1 textbox placed inside gridview itemtemplate, not inside page. in reality you may have a lot of txt_test1 textboxes (one textbox per row from sds_store). and if you want to get those textboxes - you should iterate through grv_test.Rows and try to locate your textboxes by grv_test.Rows[index].FindControl("txt_test1")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step1 :** You can use `FindControl()` function to get the required `TextBox` Control from the `GridView`
**Step2 :** Cast the Identified Control to `TextBox`
**Step3:** use the `Text` property to get the Text from the `Control`

Try This:

```
protected void btn_test2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)grv_test.Rows[grv.SelectedIndex].FindControl("txt_test1");
             string test = txt.Text;

            lbl_result.Text = "You have changed the textbox to " + test;
        }
```

Comment: @Minelava: great, I'm Glad tobe Help of you.

Comment: There is a slight problem. It can work fine but unfortunately, it can only work for the first button. Is there the way to display the message if I press the second button or third button.

Comment: yes thatswhy i have specified Rows[index] here Index is the selected Row Index, could you try with selectedRowIndex?

Comment: Can you show me an example how to use selectedRowIndex? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41462/discussion-between-minelava-and-sudhakar)

Answer (score 2):

You can't access `TextBox` inside GridViewControl directly with its `ID`.

Use `FindControl`  Method To GridView Items.

See the below example

```
    protected void btn_test1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          TextBox txt_test1=  grv_test.Rows[0].FindControl("txt_test1") as TextBox;
            if (txt_test1!= null)
            {
                string value = txt_test1.Text;
                //add your code here
            }
        }
     }

   protected void btn_test2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           TextBox txt_test1= grv_test.Rows[1].FindControl("txt_test1") as TextBox;
            if (txt_test1!= null)
            {
                string value = txt_test1.Text;
                //add your code here
            }

     }

   protected void btn_test3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           TextBox txt_test1= grv_test.Rows[2].FindControl("txt_test1") as TextBox;
            if (txt_test1!= null)
            {
                string value = txt_test1.Text;
                //add your code here
            }

     }
```

Comment: There is a slight problem. It can work fine but unfortunately, it can only work for the last button. Is there the way to display the message if I press the second button or third button.

Comment: It works as well. But the problem is because my data will changed dynamically from the database.

Comment: Actually you are following wrong methodology here. Try to use CommandField  Template For Better Code.

Comment: I will try and inform you about it later.

Comment: Is it okay to show me an example of CommandField Template? I can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: Okay I have finally solved it. But instead of using CommandField Template I used CommandArgument and this grv_test.Rows[int.Parse(btn.CommandArgument) - 1]